# Towerjs locales error

Tags: node.js, npm, locale, path-finding, towerjs

I am experimenting with towerjs.  I just followed the instructions to create a project.

```
npm install tower -g
npm install grunt -g
mongod
tower new app
cd app
npm install
```

And when I try to start the server for the project I get the following error:

```
GT@ubuntu:~/work/app$ node server.js 

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/GT/work/app/config/localesundefineden.coffee'
    at Object.statSync (fs.js:422:18)
    at Function.stat (/home/GT/work/app/node_modules/pathfinder/lib/pathfinder/file.js:21:17)
    at Function.isDirectory (/home/GT/work/app/node_modules/pathfinder/lib/pathfinder/file.js:165:19)
    at Function.isFile (/home/GT/work/app/node_modules/pathfinder/lib/pathfinder/file.js:169:20)
    at Function.files (/home/GT/work/app/node_modules/pathfinder/lib/pathfinder/file.js:137:18)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/GT/work/app/node_modules/tower/packages/tower-application/server/application.coffee:157:22)
    at /home/GT/work/app/node_modules/tower/packages/tower-support/shared/callbacks.coffee:141:28
    at /home/GT/work/app/node_modules/tower/packages/tower-support/shared/shared.coffee:307:22
    at SupportCallback.run (/home/GT/work/app/node_modules/tower/packages/tower-support/shared/callbacks.coffee:204:18)
    at /home/GT/work/app/node_modules/tower/packages/tower-support/shared/callbacks.coffee:110:25
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

With further investigation

```
_path = require('path')    
_path.sep
```

seems to return `undefined`.  Why would it not return `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so the problem was that I had to update node to the latest version (v0.8.8).  My bad.

Comment: This is a bug, please post it here: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/issues (I'll get to this either way though). Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

After cd'ing into your new app and installing all the node modules with "npm install" run "cake watch". This will create the files and templates tower needs. Many of the doc's and instructions are out of date, though I'm pretty sure that's the next major project for tower: getting those up to date.